# Get an error when trying to import a CSV using Google Bigquery CLI with backslash as an escape character

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When trying to upload a csv file to BigQuery with the following params:

```
bq load --quote='"' --null_marker='\\N' --source_format=CSV sendpulse.user_orders gs://data-sendpulse/user_orders_3.csv
```

I get an error when trying to parse the following row:

```
"0","63800.00","1","0","Service \"Startup Pack\""
```

Obviously, Bigquery doesn't treat backslash as an escape character for inner quotes, but is there a way to specify backslash as an escape character?

Tried different options and always got errors.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Quote in a quoted csv value is escaped with another quote and there is no setting for an escape character.

I don't see a better workaround than replacing all \" with ' or "" in your files.

Comment: @Eugene Krall
Share the link to the bug you created (if) with the community. Cheers!

Comment: I couldn't find it, opened https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73882854